# Best step to create simple TeamViewer clone

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to create a Teamviewer clone. Basically, I need it to work on all 3 major platforms (Win, Mac, Linux). I'm racking my brains to try to solve using NodeJS + Electron DesktopCapture to capture video, and transmute via P2P

I was thinking of doing with https://recordrtc.org instead of electron, since it works right from the browser, and I could only later package it to an executable.

But I think my biggest problems are:

1) How do I take the real time video capture from Electron / RecordRTC and stream it via a server? I can only get the recorded file later (.webm), but this is useless.

2) How will I control another user's mouse and keyboard? RobotJS, maybe? as if I were going to watch the video for 1 channel and contrast the keyboard and mouse for another?

I know how to program, I just need a light!

It's for my job! (Freelancer)

Ty <3

Comment: Hello, you can use the VNC SDK, but I'm not sure they have something for javascript https://www.realvnc.com/en/developer/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I forgot to say that I can't use private software as it will sell monthly to customers